# Using coffeescript with backbone.js issues

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to follow along the excellent tutorial backbonerails produced by Brian Mann. Unfortunately (for me because I'm a noob) he's using coffeescript.  What's confusing is my assumptions of the following code:

```
class App.Views.Users extends Backbone.View
```

I believed was the equivalent of:

```
Users = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

in plain javascript.  However, when I place the coffeescript code in trycoffeescript I get:

```
var _ref,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if     (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() {   this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new   ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

App.Views.Users = (function(_super) {
  __extends(Users, _super);

  function Users() {
    _ref = Users.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    return _ref;
  }

  return Users;

})(Backbone.View);
```

My question is am I wrong in my assumption of what plain javascript should produce, am I incorrectly approaching the way to interpret the coffee script, or am I beyond hope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes in coffeescript can't guarantee that the classes they're extending have an `extend` method, so it wouldn't be possible for the coffeescript to compile to `Backbone.View.extend`, without specifically requiring all the classes it's used with to provide the `extend` method.

However, if you look at the source of [_.extend](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-76) (which Backbone uses) you'll see that it's fairly similar to the `__extends` method that coffeescript generates and uses.

The coffeescript compiled version is obviously more verbose, but in practice I've never noticed a difference between `class MyView extends Backbone.View` and `MyView = Backbone.View.extends({}};` so you can probably use whichever one you prefer.

EDIT: One possible difference is actually the `super` coffeescript keyword, which will only work if you're using coffeescript classes.  However, you should still be able to replicate that functionality with `.extends` by calling the superclass function directly.